# how to write a common method for two generated classes in different packages but all same methods in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics

So I have two XSD generated classes. They have all methods common and all methods of both classes have the same parameters as well. They are in different packages. How can I write a common method where I can do it once for both classes.
I am trying to present the scenario as below:-

```
package a.b.c;
class x{
void m(){};
int n(){};
string o(){};
}
```

Other one

```
package a.b.d;
class x{
void m(){};
int n(){};
string o(){};
}
```

Comment: „*…xsd generated classes…*“ — Let's see your xsd? — „*…They are in different packages…*“ — Are those different packages in different namespaces? — „*…I am trying to present the scenario as below…*“ — What have you tried already?

Comment: Can't share xsd here. yes they are in different namesapces too. I tried using generics to write the common method but that's not possible since there is no common class there.Tried with object class too but it also asks for typecast which takes back to same place.
I wan't to cut down the lines of code that are being repeated in the common methods in the both classes. Not looking to write a new interface or parent class either.

Comment: „*…Can't share xsd here…*“ — Set aside a few minutes to read SO's [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'll summarize that page in case you can't spare a few minutes: «*We don't ask you to share your **exact** XSD, just something similar enough that makes it less of a hassle for people to try to help you*». You know? Like you did with *`class x`* and *`class y`*?

Answer (score 1):

If the two classes share a method, that sounds `very` much like they need to have a common ancestor class, having that method and `extend` that base class by both your classes. You can of course `extend` classes of different packages:

```
public class ChildClass extends com.the.other.package.BaseClass {
    public void foo() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or a common Interface.

Comment: these are two classes generated from an xsd file.

Comment: „*…these are two classes generated from an xsd file…*“ — How's about you show us that xsd file? TIA.

Comment: @NomadMaker the method is common. It's not only a common ability, but the common ability is the exact same, according to my understanding.